# Como escapar caracteres especiais?

Tags: lua

Preciso que a saída seja um caracter especial de uma seta apontando para a direita (→) por exemplo, cujo o código Unicode é U+1F812. Tentei de escrever de várias formas sempre com o *\* ou *%* precedendo o código Unicode (semelhante ao escrever uma tabulação ou quebra de linha) e obtenho o seguinte erro:

`` bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"\u2191"' ``

Como deve ser a sintaxe para o output destes caracteres especiais e no que UTF-8, UTF-32 etc. interferem nisto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É preciso instalar a biblioteca com suporte para *UTF-8*, senão você não conseguirá usar.

Caso tenha vá fazer a instalação pelo `luarocks`, verifique o diretório das bibliotecas do *Lua*, os arquivos podem não estar no diretório necessário.

```
$ luarocks install utf8
# ou
$ luarocks install lua-utf8
```

**Recomento o primeiro.**

## Como usar?

```
utf8 = require "utf8"
seta = utf8.char(2191) -- Nos meus testes o valor 9658 retornou uma seta
print(seta)
```

Answer (score 1):

Em Lua 5.3, você pode usar `"\u{2191}"`. As chaves são obrigatórias.

Lua 5.3 também inclui uma bibioteca `utf8` e você pode usar `utf8.char(2191)`.